# Detect if Linked Layer Topology is enabled on a computer

Tags: c#, networking

Our support team has diagnosed some specific areas of a computer's configuration that may cause slowness in our Network-based database application.  I have been tasked with creating a tool to test for possible slowing concerns.  I am having problems detecting if Linked Layer Topology is enabled in Windows for their active network adapter.  I have a method for finding the active (most used) network adapter.

Is there a way to detect Linked Layer Topology and how do I test for it?

Comment: It appears as a Windows service in recent releases of Windows. Its name is `lltdsvc`. You could check its status. This is only a rough indicator though, since the feature can be disabled on a per-adapter basis. I couldn't find a straight-forward way to query the network interfaces for this feature

Comment: Very insightful.  Thanks.  That directed my attention to places that store network connection information but I am still coming up empty handed.  If I still can't find it, I will point my program to the service.  I'll just flag it as "advisory" not a "required" change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a pure .Net solution, but seems to work.  Function accepts the name of the local area connection and a protocol name.  I have a link to a site that has a lot of different protocol driver names, but the ones you want are included in the code.

This uses nvspbind.exe, which you can get from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspbind.

***CODE***

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //check Link-Layer Topology Discover Mapper I/O Driver
        bool result1 = IsProtocalEnabled("Local Area Connection", "ms_lltdio");
        //check Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder
        bool result2 = IsProtocalEnabled("Local Area Connection", "ms_rspndr");
    }

    private static bool IsProtocalEnabled(string adapter, string protocol)
    {
        var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nvspbind.exe");
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/o \"{0}\" {1}", adapter, protocol);

        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return output.Contains("enabled");
    }
}
```

I got the protocol driver names from here: http://djseppie.wordpress.com/category/windows/scripting/

Comment: AWESOME.  I have searched all over but kept coming up with nothing.  This was exactly what I needed!  I did have to modify your code to handle for possible multiple network cards so my code's return statement looks like this

            foreach (string strline in output.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (strline.Contains(adapter))
                    return strline.Contains("enabled");
            }

            return output.Contains("enabled");
This divides each NIC onto it's own line

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think it would return anything but exact matches unless you passed in a search string like '%Local Area Connection%', good to know though.  Glad it works for you.